# magento php memory limit issue

Tags: magento2

Iam facing an issue while installing extension through magento web setup wizard 
[image]

I have created phpinfo file and tried/checked memory limit is 1024M and i have added php.ini or tried .htaccess for this issue but still i am facing the same thing same issue . I have cleared cache , upgrade , static-content . i dont know how to fix this issue .
that is phpinfo link
http://box5738.temp.domains/~thebarkc/info.php

Answer (score 2):

What about memory limit for PHP-CLI?

You need to increase memory limit for PHP-CLI too.

Run `php -i | grep 'memory_limit'` to see memory limit for PHP-CLI